# NSSpeechSynthesizer Saving to URL

Tags: multithreading, swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch, text-to-speech

I'm creating a MacOS application that generates dialog files from a tab-delimited text file. The text file is formatted *(output filename) [tab] (text to be spoken to that file)*. I got the program working perfectly running in the main thread, but this blocked the UI, of course. When I moved the meat of the application to a User Initiated thread, I unblocked the UI, but now it occasionally and randomly speaks a line out the speaker instead of to a file. A file is still created, but it's of zero duration. If the script contains 1,000 lines, it might get through the whole thing perfectly, or it might "speak" ten or more of them out the speaker. It's almost always different lines each time.

This is the code that speaks to a file:

```
// Set URL to save file to disk
if let speechFileURL = NSURL(string: speechFilePath) {
    speechSynth.startSpeakingString(spokenText, toURL: speechFileURL)  // Speak to file
}
else {
    dialogAlert("Invalid File: ", text: speechFileName)
}

while(NSSpeechSynthesizer.isAnyApplicationSpeaking() == true) {
    if self.gUserClickedStop {
        speechSynth.stopSpeaking()
        self.gIsSpeaking = false
        break
    }
}
```

This is the call to the function that parses the script and generates the speech files:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) { [unowned self] in
    self.parseTheScript()
}
```

As mentioned above, calling parseTheScript() without wrapping it in the Grand Central Dispatch call makes it work perfectly, except for the blocking issue.

I'm new to programming in Swift and the idea of multithreaded programming, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm stumped as to how to fix this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit to add...

This is the entire function that parses the text file and generates the dialog files:

```
    // This opens the text file and generates the spoken audio files
func parseTheScript() {
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    print("Chosen path: \(scriptFileTextField.stringValue)")   // debug
    if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(scriptFileTextField.stringValue) {
        print("File exists")
        do {
            outputFilename.stringValue = ""
            scriptToSpeak.stringValue = ""
            outputFilename.hidden = false
            scriptToSpeak.hidden = false
            progressBar.minValue = 0
            progressBar.doubleValue = 0.0
            progressBar.hidden = false
            filenameLabel.hidden = false

            let text = try String(contentsOfFile: scriptFileTextField.stringValue, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let lines: [String] = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
            var progressEndValue = Double(lines.count)
            progressBar.maxValue = progressEndValue

            let speechSynth = NSSpeechSynthesizer.init()
            let theVoice = gVoiceList[voiceListPopup.indexOfSelectedItem - 1]   // Not sure why it's off by one
            speechSynth.setVoice(theVoice)

            for line in lines {
                let thisLine: [String] = line.componentsSeparatedByString("\t") // Split the line at the tab character
                if (thisLine.count == 2) {                  // Did the line split into two parts?
                    let speechFileName = thisLine[0]
                    let spokenText = thisLine[1]
                    outputFilename.stringValue = speechFileName
                    scriptToSpeak.stringValue = spokenText
                    let speechFilePath = destinationFolderTextField.stringValue + speechFileName + ".aif"        // Build the path string for the output speech file
                    print("Filename: \(speechFilePath)")
                    print("SpokenText: \(spokenText)")

                    if(gSpeakToFile) {
                        // Set URL to save file to disk
                        if let speechFileURL = NSURL(string: speechFilePath) {
                            speechSynth.startSpeakingString(spokenText, toURL: speechFileURL)  // Speak to file
                        }
                        else {
                            dialogAlert("Invalid File: ", text: speechFileName)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        speechSynth.startSpeakingString(spokenText) // Speak to audio output
                    }

                    while(NSSpeechSynthesizer.isAnyApplicationSpeaking() == true) {
                        if self.gUserClickedStop {
                            speechSynth.stopSpeaking()
                            self.gIsSpeaking = false
                            break
                        }
                    }

                    progressBar.incrementBy(1.0)
                }
                if gUserClickedStop {
                    gUserClickedStop = false
                    gIsSpeaking = false
                    progressEndValue = 0
                    generateButton.title = "Start"
                    break
                }

            }
            gIsSpeaking = false
            progressBar.doubleValue = progressEndValue
            generateButton.title = "Start"
            filenameLabel.hidden = true
            outputFilename.stringValue = ""
            scriptToSpeak.stringValue = ""

        } catch let error as NSError {
            dialogAlert("Error:", text: String(error.localizedDescription))
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("File does not exist")
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think it runs "perfectly" on the main thread either. You need to properly implement the delegate methods, e.g. `speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking:` in order to get notified when `startSpeakingString` is finished. You may examine an example first to figure out how to use `NSSpeechSyntheziser`.

Comment: Admittedly, I have been treating the delegate methods as optional, so I'll dig into that further. By "perfectly," I meant the application produced exactly the results I was seeking.

Comment: I don't think you're showing enough code. When does the first snippet of code execute? Where is the code for self.parseTheScript()?

Comment: I've added the entire parseTheScript function.

Comment: @MakerOfSound - do you actually get aiff (or anything) output by NSSpeechSynthsizer? I'ved used this class in an app of mine for a while, though I've never previously used the toURL option. When I call it, it returns that all is well, and indeed all seems to be well, except no files are produced.

Comment: I was getting aiff output, but I have not revisited this issue since I originally posted this question. I was having problems with MacOS versions and the group for whom I was creating this application. In the end, we went with a basic AppleScript tool to do the work. I was having an issue where it would create the AIFF files, but they were of zero bytes size. I was only able to get it to work properly on specific MacOS versions, but not what most of the machines here were running.